# Truncated Taylor series of the exponential

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Let $N \in \mathbb N^*$, $\delta > 0$, $t > 0$ and consider
\begin{equation}
f(t,\delta, N)= e^{-t/\delta} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{(t/\delta)^k}{k!}. \qquad \qquad \qquad (1)
\end{equation}
Let now $N = \lceil\delta^{-\gamma}\rceil$, with $0 < \gamma < 1$. Can we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\delta \to 0} f(t,\delta,\lceil \delta^{-\gamma}\rceil)=0,
\end{equation}
for all $t > 0$?

The reasoning is that if $N \to \infty$ (for $\delta$ fixed), then the sum tends to $e^{t/\delta}$ and therefore $f(t,\delta,N)\to 1$. If on the other hand $\delta \to 0$, for $N$ fixed, we have that $f(t,\delta,N)\to 0$ since the exponential goes faster to zero than the polynomial to infinity. In this case, we let $\delta \to 0$ and simultaneously $N \to \infty$, but with a "slower pace". Can we conclude that the limit is zero? If yes, how?

**Edit:**

After some reasoning I came up with
$$
f(t,\delta,N)= \frac{\Gamma(N, t/\delta)}{(N-1)!},
$$
with $\Gamma(\cdot, \cdot)$ the upper incomplete Gamma function. I implemented this in Matlab, and the interesting behaviour is that if $N=\delta^{-1}$, then the limit (1) is $1/2$ if $0 <t \leq 1$ and it is 0 if $t > 1$. If $N=\delta^{-\gamma}$, with $\gamma \in (0, 1)$, the limit is 0, and if $N = \delta^{-\gamma}$, with $\gamma > 1$, then the limit is 1, independently of $t$.

Comment: my bad, I misread

Comment: Speaking intuitively, the question comes down to identifying the dominant terms in the series for the exponential. If you think about this, the dominant terms are necessarily around $t \delta^{-1}$: until that point, the terms are rapidly growing, and after that they are rapidly decaying.

Comment: Sorry Ian but I did not understand your comment. In my intuition (and some computations seem to confirm this) if $\gamma$ is different from $1$ then $t$ does not play a role in the result

Comment: If $\gamma$ is different from $1$ and $t$ is different from $0$ then asymptotically you are not cutting off the sum anywhere near $t\delta^{-1}$ and so you either have "all the important terms" ($\gamma>1$) or "none of the important terms" ($0<\gamma<1$).

Comment: Ok gotcha. How would you rigorously prove this?

Comment: For one direction, consider $\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{(t/\delta)^k}{k!} \leq \sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{(t/\delta)^k}{N! N^{k-N}}=\frac{N^N}{N!} \sum_{k=N}^\infty \left ( \frac{t}{N\delta} \right )^k$. By Stirling, this is just a little bit bigger than $\frac{(ec)^N}{1-c}$ where $c=\frac{t}{N\delta}$. So it goes to zero if $\frac{t}{N\delta}<e^{-1}$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, so this proves that in case $\gamma > 1$, then $f \to 1$, correct?

Comment: That, and (if I didn't make a mistake) that it also converges to $1$ if $N=C \delta^{-1}$ and $t<(Ce)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for your help in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let $x=t/\delta$ for the moment.

The main point is that $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ is within a polynomial factor of $\left ( \frac{xe}{k} \right )^k$, by Stirling. (It's within a bounded factor of $\frac{(xe)^k}{k^{k+1/2}}$ but this is overkill for this application.)

So for $0<c<1$, the sum of all the terms with $k>x(1+c)$ behaves basically like $\left ( \frac{e}{1+c} \right )^{x(1+c)} \frac{c+1}{c}$. This is the dominant term times $\frac{1}{1-r}$ where $r=\frac{1}{1+c}$ is the common ratio of the bounding geometric series.

Similarly for the first $x(1-c)$ terms you have a bound like $\left ( \frac{e}{1-c} \right )^{x(1-c)} \frac{1}{c}$.

Returning to your setting, if $\gamma>1$ then you exclude only the terms past $x(1+c)$ where $c \to \infty$ as $\delta \to 0$, and so the error goes to zero.

If $\gamma<1$ then you exclude all the terms past $x(1-c)$ for $c \to 1$ as $\delta \to 0$ and so the terms you are including become negligible relative to $e^x$, i.e. the error goes to $1$.

If instead you look at $N \sim C \delta^{-1}$ then the above bounds properly come into play.

Comment: Thanks. I may be slow, but I'm not grasping it. Could you be a bit more precise? "The error" is $e^{t/\delta} - \sum_{k=N}^{\infty} \cdots$?

Comment: @G.Gare The error I'm referring to is $1-e^{-t/\delta} \sum \dots$.